# jQuery hover dropdown menu- dropdowns disappear as soon as you hover away from parent div. how to avoid this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

progress and issue (its the offices dropdown): [jsfiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/r78tpqch/2/)

**Code:**

```
    $(function() {
    $('#dropbutton').hover(function(e) {
    $('#myDropdown').toggle();
  });
});
```

How do I either capture the hover outside or just keep the display for the div in child dropdown elements. Thanks!

Comment: It would be better to structure this using an unordered list, with nested sub-lists. No JS needed then.

Comment: Just add the dropdown element selector with the range of selectors specified with the `.hover()` method, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/r78tpqch/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need fo js, just add this css code:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
  display: block;
}
```

This will display the **dropdown-content** when you hover on the parent (**dropdown**)

**See snippet:**

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 19.5%;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: black;
  outline: 0;
  /*invalid
  text-style: bold;*/
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}




.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 4px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
<button class="dropbtn"> Home </button>
</div>

<div class="navItem dropdown" style="display:inline">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" id="dropbutton">Offices</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Regional</a>
    <a href="https://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank">Global</a>
    <a href="https://www.apple.com" target="_blank">Local</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
<button class="dropbtn"> Who we are</button>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
<button class="dropbtn"> Contact </button>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
<button class="dropbtn" id="searchBox"> Search </button>
</div>

<p>
  Page content goes here. As you click on dropdown or anything, this text remains here. You can try clicking on the Office dropdown on the menu above.
</p>
```

Comment: Dang! Thank you my friend. Such a simple and powerful solution right there. appreciate it.

Comment: btw, how would I do this without using the button tags? CSS is underrated..

Comment: Tried and I think I butchered it big time. https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/ndq5d94g/ Thoughts? Btw, the reason I'm trying to avoid buttons is because putting links around button seems like a PITA.

Comment: nice. close..how do I get it to spread evenly and have drop down items flow evenly like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/qve06wjf/

Comment: dang. saint of the day! Thanks mate. one final question- you know that little section between Offices and the first dropdown titled regional..if you gradually move your hover cursor around there the dropdown disappears. technically correct I think but how do you typically avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the jQuery completely with CSS.

First you need to add:

```
#dropbutton:hover + .dropdown-content,
.dropdown-content:hover {
display: block;
}
```

This will open / close the menu.

I've also replaced the `margins` on the menu with `border-bottom`:

```
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.dropdown-content a:nth-child(1) {
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

Here's a complete example:

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 19.5%;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: black;
  outline: 0;
  /*invalid
  text-style: bold;*/
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 4px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.dropdown-content a:nth-child(1) {
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

#dropbutton:hover + .dropdown-content,
.dropdown-content:hover {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
<button class="dropbtn"> Home </button>
</div>

<div class="navItem dropdown" style="display:inline">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" id="dropbutton">Offices</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Regional</a>
    <a href="https://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank">Global</a>
    <a href="https://www.apple.com" target="_blank">Local</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
<button class="dropbtn"> Who we are</button>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
<button class="dropbtn"> Contact </button>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
<button class="dropbtn" id="searchBox"> Search </button>
</div>

<p>
  Page content goes here. As you click on dropdown or anything, this text remains here. You can try clicking on the Office dropdown on the menu above.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, answer and full code. appreciate it